# Electric current felt over the case occasionally!

Tags: current, noise, cases, shock

We have made one vacuum former for dental medical usage.

In testing, the operator reported:

1-Electric current felt  over the case of the  device occasionally!

2-hanging in some routines occasionally! ( maybe  noise or ...)

So in my country we have only phase and null in home electrical wiring, so I guess this is because of ground fault current.

The circuit schematic is here:

[image: Schematic and photos]

Controller part's Circuit Schematic:

[image]

[Or in this PDF](https://www.4shared.com/s/f6ztwDDiwca)

We have used one transformer at the power source with isolation from metal case body, does this transformer prevent from  the ground electric current fault in the device's case (isolate the circuit from this ground current !),if yes does why this happen?

We used ordinary electrolytic capacitor and the second side of transformer as input of the controller board as you can see in the middle pic in second row , they are black  cap on the top C6 And C7 with value of almost 3300 uf. Is this related to case electrical shock current?

So do you know why this happened and how could we solve this electric current shock problem and could this shock current could be the reason for the second problem (hanging in some routines occasionally?)

Comment: What kind of y-capacitors you use?

Comment: More than a few issues stand out. The first I would like to ask about is in the bottom left picture. Is that a metal enclosure, and is that a power transformer on the board in the bottom left of the enclosure, and is there adequate isolation between the solder side of that board and the enclosure? It looks more than a little suspicious, and is a lot more important than anything else in your project.

Comment: My laptop does same thing, you cap put the HP logo on the device :)

Comment: You have an uninsulated live chassis laptop? ;)

Comment: Yes,that is a power transformer on the board in the bottom left of the enclosure with isolation from body's aluminum  of case.(shape edited)

Comment: we used ordinary electrolytic capacitor and the second side of transformer as input of the controller board as you can see in the middle pic in second row , they are black  cap on the top C6 And C7 with value of almost 3300 uf .

Comment: Given that you have no ground on the power cable, I'd think you would want to insulate everything inside from the housing.  Any connection from your circuit to the housing could put the housing at line voltage if something in your cicuit fails just the right way.

Comment: Is the blue thing really a transformer, or is it a self contained switching power supply module?  It doesn't look like a simple transformer to me.

Comment: By the way, I can't download your pdf.  The site requires a logon, and I'm not going to sign up for just one file. (No, I'm not on facebook or any of the other offered sign on services.)

Comment: "**Is the blue thing really a transformer**" : yes this is one kind of Chinese Transformers .